# Why isn't there a faq or info about "what is cycling"?

Tags: discussion

This is a website focused on cycling community, and why isn't there a dedicated post, or info, about what cycling actually is? This is outrageous.

> Today I brought a friend to show off this website dedicated about cycling. His first question what "What is cycling", I typed it is search and had nothing, this is humiliating

I have asked a [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/what-is-cycling-styles-forms). And Everybody should contribute to this page.

Comment: If someone had no idea that you can ride a bicycle (which seems to be what you're asking), would this site be of any use to them?

Comment: @Piskvor, It certainly can be the site to learn from, can't it?

Comment: I'm not sure. From what I've seen, the site presupposes that you do know the absolute basics - "this is a bike, it has pedals, you push them with your feet, it also has handlebars, you steer with those using your hands, and you sit on this". I'd say that there are other sites for questions like "what is a bicycle?" (e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle)) . For contrast, would you go to StackOverflow asking "what is programming"?

Comment: @Piskvor, Thats a good point with stackoverflow. I now understand

Comment: See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Answer (score 3):

From the [FAQ](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Failing that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycling

Comment: Ok, since you are pulling stuff from the site. Read [this](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/about) It says `Bicycles - Stack Exchange is that tiny asterisk in the middle.` Not just wiki is it?

Comment: You miss the point, perhaps deliberately, in that Bicycles.SE builds on the information already available elsewhere. There's no point in repeating the wikipedia entry - so if someone doesn't know what cycling is, this is not the place for them.

Comment: Unsliced is right. This is a question which has no definable answer. At least partly because cycling is different for every participant. For my wife, it's exercise. For me, it's a sporting event and a lifestyle and my job. Whatever it is to you, this is a question best answered in a different format.